# What's the difference between addAll() vs followedBy() in Dart lists?

Tags: list, dart, concatenation, iterable

I need to concatenate two lists in Dart and saw that there are at least two different methods to do so. One is `list1.addAll(list2)` and the other is `list1.followedBy(list2)`.
I wonder what's the difference? The documentation refers to the latter as "lazy concatenation". Does it mean that under the hood the elements are copied in the first case, but only referenced in the latter? Or is there something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list1.addAll(list2)` grows and mutates `list1` to include the elements of `list2`.  If `list2` has *m* elements, then memory consumption from  `list1.addAll(list2)` will grow by O(m).

More visually, if you have:

```
list1                  list2
+---+---+---+---+      +---+---+
| o | o | o | o |      | o | o |
+-|-+-|-+-|-+-|-+      +-|-+-|-+
  |   |   |   |          |   |
  v   v   v   v          v   v
  A   B   C   D          E   F
```

then `list1.addAll(list2)` will produce:

```
list1                       list2
+---+---+---+---+---+---+   +---+---+
| o | o | o | o | o | o |   | o | o |
+-|-+-|-+-|-+-|-+-|-+-|-+   +-|-+-|-+
  |   |   |   |   |   |       |   |
  v   v   v   v    \   \______|__ |
  A   B   C   D     \   ______/  \|
                     \ /          |
                      |           v
                      v           F
                      E
```

Note that mutating `list2` afterward will not affect the contents of `list1`.

`list1.followedBy(list2)` returns an `Iterable` (*not* a `List`).  When you iterate over the that `Iterable`, you will iterate over `list1` and then iterate over `list2`. `list1.followedBy(list2)` does not not mutate `list1` and should not allocate a new `List`.  Memory consumption from `list1.followedBy(list2)` will grow by O(1) since no `List`s are grown nor created.

In this case, mutating `list2` afterward *will* affect the `Iterable` returned by `followedBy`:

```dart
void main() {
  var list1 = [1, 2, 3];
  var list2 = [4, 5, 6];
  
  var list1Copy = [...list1];
  list1Copy.addAll(list2);
  
  print(list1Copy); // Prints: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
   
  var concatenated = list1.followedBy(list2);
  print(concatenated.toList()); // Prints: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

  list2.add(7);
  print(list1Copy); // Prints: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  print(concatenated.toList()); // Prints: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
}
```

Comment: Very comprehensive explanation! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lazy loading (in this case lazy concatenation) means that some resources are not evaluated before they are necessary. By contrast, eager loading (or eager concatenation) means that the resource is fully evaluated.

So, lazy concatenation means that the concatenation is known to be executed, but its final evaluation is postponed until it is needed. Also, eager concatenation means that the whole concatenation process is fully done.